# excel cell formatting

Tags: c#, excel

How can I change the cell format to be text in Excel programatically?

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
```

for text

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
```

for a date.

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "#,###"
```

for money, etc.

Comment: It is 2012:07:17:20:27 and you Sir, are my hero.

Answer (score 4):

The way that I answer this and other excel queries it to record a macro in Excel, perform the action that I want to see how to do, and then look at the macro to see what it recorded.

Doing that, this questions answer is:

Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

Answer (score 0):

**To apply a style to a named range**

Create a new style and set its attributes.

```
Excel.Style style = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Styles.Add("NewStyle", missing);

style.Font.Name = "Verdana";
style.Font.Size = 12;
style.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
style.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Gray);
style.Interior.Pattern = Excel.XlPattern.xlPatternSolid;
```

Create a NamedRange control, assign text to it, and then apply the new style.

```
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.NamedRange rangeStyles = this.Controls.AddNamedRange(this.Range["A1", missing], "rangeStyles");

rangeStyles.Value2 = "'Style Test";
rangeStyles.Style = "NewStyle";
rangeStyles.Columns.AutoFit();
```