# Updating Excel Cell with Non-Numeric Data in C#

Tags: c#, sql, excel, oledb

I have a query that is

```
ExcelQuery = "Update [Sheet1$] "
               +"set CITIZEN_ID = #" + value 
               + " where CITIZEN_ID = " + value;
```

As you can see, I'm essentially just prepending a "#" to the CITIZEN_ID field. value is a int/numeric value. So if I had "256" in the CITIZEN_ID column it would be converted to "#256"

When I execute this I get an OleDbException `Syntax error in date in query expression` so I surrounded part of the query in single quotes like this,

```
ExcelQuery = "Update [Sheet1$] "
               +"set CITIZEN_ID = '#" + value + "' "
               +"where CITIZEN_ID = " + value;
```

With that I get yet another OleDbException this time with, `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

I'm guessing for some reason the CITIZEN_ID fields don't want to take anything besides a plain number. Is there any way I can remedy this to get that pound symbol in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just change the number format so it shows a '#' before each number in the CITIZEN_ID field.

This doesn't solve your stated problem .. but it avoids it :-)

**Update:**
This StackOverflow Question ( [excel-cell-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292812/excel-cell-formatting)) talks about cell formatting using C#

Comment: I suppose so. How would I go about this programmatically?

Comment: I've only done this from Perl .. what you need to do is change the cell's format. There will be an API to do this!

Comment: I'll get it figured out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to use SQL to `INSERT` a text value into a column which the DBMS (the Access Database Engine) sees as `DOUBLE FLOAT` and hence getting a type mismatch error. You may be able to change registry values to convince the engine to consider the column to be text, see:

[External Data - Mixed Data Types](http://www.dicks-blog.com/archives/2004/06/03/external-data-mixed-data-types/)